# NoMethodError when I try to acces a field of an object taken from the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say that I have a model called Tweet with the following fields

- 1. id
- 2. content
- 3. created_at
- 4. user_id
- 5. original_tweet_id

Now let's say I query this model with the following query @tweet = Tweet.where(id: 64) and this query returns an object with no fields nil.

Why can't I acces a field by doing @tweet.id or @tweet.content ? I get NoMethodError  `NoMethodError: undefined method`id' for `#Tweet::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000006e6ce80`

I got the error trying to execute `@original.id` on this object that resulted from the query :

```
@original
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Tweet id: 64, content: "Unde et nisi blanditiis vel occaecati soluta praes...", user_id: 4, created_at: "2014-12-22 08:56:46", updated_at: "2014-12-22 08:56:46", picture: nil, group: nil, original_tweet_id: nil>]>
```

Something from my ruby knowledge is really missing...help!!!

Comment: you can do `@tweet.first.id` or `@original.first.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because where returns a collection not a single object

So instead of

```
@tweet = Tweet.where(id: 64)
```

You want

```
@tweet = Tweet.find(64)
```

because you're using the id

Comment: god! yes this is the right answer :P I shall check it when it will let me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please use `Tweet.where(id: 64).first` since `find` has been deprecated. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

Comment: @FabiandePabian, no it's [not](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)

Answer (score 2):

@original is not a Tweet instance but an ActiveRecord::Relation

If you want to access the id of your Tweet directly you should define @original like this

```
@original = Tweet.find_by_id(64)
```

or

```
@original = Tweet.where(id: 64).first
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, It returns a collection of object of Active Record Relation

so for specific record

`@original.first.id` gives you `64`

or

```
  @tweet = Tweet.find(64)
  @tweet.id #64
  @tweet.content # "Unde et nisi blanditiis vel occaecati soluta praes..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead, you need to add `first`

```
@tweet = Tweet.where(id: 64).first
```